# Mac Bash Script fails on Do?

Tags: macos, qt, bash, shell, terminal

This script needs to run on Mac OSX. The following script is to build a QT QRC (resource file definition) which is nothing more than an XML file with a different extension. I've tested each piece of the script isolated in terminal on the mac. All is as it should work, but I can't get the for loop to execute properly.

This script should:

1. List all files in the current directory
2. Strip out the ./ produced by the find
3. Create the proper XML

Here's what the result should look like:

```
<RCC>
    <qresource prefix="/">
        <file>login.html</file>
        <file>start.html</file>
        <file>base/files.html</file>
    </qresource>
</RCC>
```

Here's my current script:

```
 #!/bin/bash
    #Define the File
        file="Resources.qrc"
    #Clear out the old file, we want a fresh one
        rm $file
    #Format the start of the QRC file
        echo "<RCC>" >> $file
        echo "  <qresource prefix=\"/\">" >> $file
        #Iterate through the directory structure recursively
            for f in $(find . -type f)
                do
                    #Ensure the file isn't one we want to ignore
                        if [[ $f != "*.qrc" && $f != "*.rc" && $f != "*.h" && $f != "*.sh" ]]
                        then
                            #Strip out the ./ for the proper QRC reference
                                echo "<file>$f</file>" | sed "s/.\///" >> $file
                        fi
                done
    #Close the QRC file up
        echo "  </qresource>" >> $file
        echo "</RCC>" >> $file
```

And this is what terminal keeps telling me:

```
'build-qrc.sh: line 11: syntax error near unexpected token `do
'build-qrc.sh: line 11: `           do
```

Any time I try to do a shell for loop it give me the same error. I've tried semi-colns and the like to no avail. Any ideas? Thanks.

---

**Here's the finalized script thanks to chepner. It generates a perfect QRC resource file for QT for use with embedding html items into a webkit driven app.**

```
#!/bin/bash
#Define the Resource File
file="AncestorSyncUIPlugin.qrc"
#Clear out the old file if it exists, we want a fresh one
if [ -f $file ] 
then
    rm $file
fi
# Use the -regex primary of find match files with the following
# extensions: qrc rc sh h. Use -not to negate that, so only files
# that don't match are returned. The -E flag is required for
# the regex to work properly. The list of files is stored in
# an array
target_files=( $(find -E . -type f -regex ".*\.(png|jpg|gif|css|html)$") )

# Use a compound statement to redirect the output from all the `echo`
# statements at once to the target file. No need to remove the old file,
# no need to append repeatedly.
{
    #Format the start of the QRC file
    echo "<RCC>"

    # Use single quotes to avoid the need to escape the " characters
    echo '  <qresource prefix="/">'

    # Iterate over the list of matched files
    for f in "${target_files[@]}"
    do
        # Use parameter expansion to strip "./" from the beginning
        # of each file
        echo "  <file>${f#./}</file>"
    done
    #Close the QRC file up
    echo "  </qresource>"
    echo "</RCC>"
} > $file
```

Comment: I just tested your script and it's working fine for me... How do you call the script on the terminal?

Comment: Either ./qrc.sh or sh qrc.sh or bash qrc.sh.  I'm on Lion. I'm kind of confused.

Comment: Did you also try `for ...; do` (without new line after semicolon)? That's the syntax I'm used to, but as I said before: your script works perfectly on my machine...

Comment: I did try that. I think my terminal is messed up. Works on other lion machines. I think I am just going to format my lappy. Bah.

Comment: @leemes: As a statement delimiter, semicolons are equivalent to newlines.

Comment: Try `set -x` at the beginning of your script (or change your shebang to `#!/bin/bash -x`) to see a trace of your script when you run it. That may give you more information and lead to a diagnosis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see any syntax errors, but `$f != "*.qrc"` shouldn't work the way you intend it. That tests the value of `f` against the literal string `*.qrc`. Here's your script, shortened using various tricks:

```
#!/bin/bash
#Define the File
file="Resources.qrc"
# Use the -regex primary of find match files with the following
# extensions: qrc rc sh h. Use -not to negate that, so only files
# that don't match are returned. The -E flag is required for
# the regex to work properly. The list of files is stored in
# an array
target_files=( $(find -E . -type f -not -regex ".*\.(q?rc|s?h)$") )

# Use a compound statement to redirect the output from all the `echo`
# statements at once to the target file. No need to remove the old file,
# no need to append repeatedly.
{
    #Format the start of the QRC file
    echo "<RCC>"

    # Use single quotes to avoid the need to escape the " characters
    echo '  <qresource prefix="/">'

    # Iterate over the list of matched files
    for f in "${target_files[@]}"
    do
        # Use parameter expansion to strip "./" from the beginning
        # of each file
        echo "    <file>${f#./}</file>"
    done
    #Close the QRC file up
    echo "  </qresource>"
    echo "</RCC>"
} > $file
```

Comment: Thanks! I appeciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

> Any time I try to do a shell for loop it give me the same error. I've tried semi-colns and the like to no avail. Any ideas?

I just had the same problem. For me, it seems to have been caused by CRLF (Windows) line endings. Once I switched to LF (Unix), everything went fine.